# How to reference a control in a specific version of library inside of apsx page

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

How can this be done on an apsx page? ie:

```
<%@ Register tagPrefix="ig" assembly="library.v5.2" namespace="library.web.ui.controls" %>

<ig:WebDataGrid id="grid1">
...
</ig:WebDataGrid>
```

I get **ambiguous reference**.

I have two versions of a library, library.v1.1 and library.v5.2. (vendor libararies. Can't change them.) Both have the same control with the same namespace. I need both of them in my project as there are controls in the older version that do not exist in the newer version.

Extern alias works for a C# file, but no solution to be found for aspx files.

Any suggestions?